# Is it possible to retrieve appointment responses from attendees?

Tags: javascript, web, outlook, office-js, add-in

Is it possible to retrieve the status of attendees in Outlook Web Add-In for an appointment/meeting? Here is a snippet similar to the code I'm working with.

```
let item = Office.context.mailbox.item,
  requiredAttendees, optionalAttendees, totalAttendees = 0;

if (item.itemType === Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Appointment) {
  requiredAttendees = item.requiredAttendees;
  optionalAttendees = item.optionalAttendees;

  if (requiredAttendees) {
    requiredAttendees.getAsync((asyncResult) => {
      console.log(asyncResult.value);
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        totalAttendees += asyncResult.value.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < asyncResult.value.length; i++) {
          console.log(asyncResult.value[i].displayName + ' | ' +
            asyncResult.value[i].appointmentResponse + ' | ' +
            asyncResult.value[i].recipientType + ' | ' +
            asyncResult.value[i].emailAddress);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
test@test.com | undefined | externalUser | test@test.com
test2@test.com | undefined | externalUser | test2@test.com
test3@test.com | undefined | externalUser | test3@test.com
```

***appointmentResponse*** is undefined.

**Stringify asyncResult.value:**
{"emailAddress":"test@test.com","displayName":"test@test.com","recipientType":"externalUser"},{"emailAddress":"test2@test.com","displayName":"test2@test.com","recipientType":"externalUser"},{"emailAddress":"test3@test.com","displayName":"test3@test.com","recipientType":"externalUser"}]

**Screenshot of asyncResult.value:**
[image]

I'm looking for something to indicate:

- No Response
- Accepted
- Declined

**Manifest Snippet**

```
          <!-- appt Compose -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="apptCmdGroupId">
                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptCmdButtonId">
                  <Label resid="apptCmdButtonLabel"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="apptCmdSuperTipTitle"/>
                    <Description resid="apptCmdSuperTipDescription"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="apptCmdEntryPointUrl"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
```

Obviously, the data is just not on this object, but curious if there's a way to get at this data point. The function getAppointmentResponse made me think it was possible... maybe incomplete implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the output when you `console.log(asyncResult.value);`? Only appointmentResponse is undefined?

Comment: @ShawnYap -- Updated the question with additional information.

Comment: I'm not too sure but it does seems like it's not exposed through `get` like the others.

Comment: Currently the feature you are requesting, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT - The documentation indicates it's a feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_5/office.emailaddressdetails?view=office-js#appointmentresponse

I'd be happy to request the feature, but reading the documentation it seems it should already be a feature. It just seems not to be fully implemented. The response type from the getAppointmentResponse is MailboxEnums.ResponseType, which is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT - Opened issue:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-reference/issues/332

Comment: You are right, my previous comment is not correct. Digging into this I've confirmed that this does NOT work on OWA or Outlook Desktop, for Appointment Compose Scenarios. However, it DOES work with Appointment READ scenarios. (which is kind of ironic)....  I'm not sure if this is a design decision or a bug, but I've notified the product team.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT - Thank you for looking into this and your prompt response. My use case for this add-in involves knowing the number of attendees, more specifically the accurate number that has responded with "accepted". I'm updating my question with the manifest snippet for AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface. Looking forward to knowing if this is something that might be implemented soon. Thanks again.

Comment: @happyhuman can you please try code which i shared here- https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/413